# How to build a dictionnary in one line:

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I would like to write this python dictionnary in just one line. Also, would it be more efficient to write it in just one line or to leave it as I wrote it so far and why ? Here is my code :

```
def buildDic(df):
    dic = {}
    hashSet = set(['aa','bb','cc','dd','aa'])
    for hashs in hashSet :
        dic[hashs]=0
    return dic
```

Thanks

Comment: `d ={n: n**2 for n in range(5)}`  for details you could refer http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_dictionary_comprehension_with_zip_from_list.php

Comment: Use [`fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys): `dict.fromkeys(hashSet, 0)`